# Should I be able to solve this integral analytically?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I solve this integral analytically? That can be done at all?
All the parameters are supposed to be bigger than zero.

[image: eq_1]

Comment: The problem trivially reduces to computing $$\int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{b(1+y)^3+c(1+y)^4+d}}\,\mathrm dy$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral